# Using SQL Server Always Encrypted feature in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am using SQL Server Always Encrypted feature of Azure SQL with .NET code. 
While it works like charm inside Entity Framework where the data can be decrypted, not sure how do I use it in stored procedures?

Let's say I have a column called `Department Id` and I have encrypted the same using Always Encrypted feature. If I want to join using Department Id to other tables and I want to decrypt it on the fly in the SQL Server stored procedure, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to join using Department Id to other tables

Use [Deterministic encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#selecting--deterministic-or-randomized-encryption):

> Using deterministic encryption allows point lookups, equality joins, grouping and indexing on encrypted columns.

---

> and I want to decrypt it on the fly in the SQL Server stored procedure, how do I do that?

You don't. The server never has access to the key. That's the point. You can *return* the value from the stored procedure but you *don't* decrypt it on the SQL side.